# Jupyter Notebook: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am adding a picture into Jupyter Notebook like below:

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image("a.png")
![title](a.png)
```

but got the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Any idea what I missed? Thanks!

Comment: it's working for me but without the last line, i guess there is something wrong with title line

Comment: what do u mean by title line? is that something I need to set separately? Thanks!

Comment: just keep the first two lines and it works and set the title separately

Comment: How do I set title separately? Could u please share an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add an image in jupyter notebook, first change the drop down from code to Markdown, then write the following code and run it

```
<img src="1.jpg" title="Title text" />
# Image 1
```